# What is the event that toggles appbar in javascript Windows 8 Metro Style App?

Tags: javascript, windows-8, windows-runtime, microsoft-metro, appbar

I am looking for the event that toggles the appbar in javascript. So it's basically the "edge-swipe" gesture event on the top/bottom edge of the screen.

For example, I want to show a text "edge swiped" on the page when the user swipe the upper or butto edge of the screen, without declaring a app bar in the page. How will I be able to do that?

I tried crossslide event and it doesn't seem to be right.

Comment: Would those [edge-based UI animations](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh465178.aspx) be helpful for you?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cross-slide won't work for you because it's a gesture that can start anywhere.

There's no edge-slide event that is exposed to a Metro app.  Windows 8 detects the edge-slide and raises the app bar for you automatically (when you have one).

Maybe they'll add one in the future, but who know's if or when, so you'll probably want to do your own gesture tracking. I'd suggest you have look at the PointerPoint class and building your own custom gesture recognizer.
A basic edge swipe should be easy enough to recognize, though you'll have to pay attention to all the pointers on screen.  For example, if I have a tablet that tracks 5 fingers and one of them edge-slides, do you recognize the gesture regardless or only if there is a single touch point active at the time?  That's up to you.

Comment: Thank you @RichardBanks, I was hoping to use a quick hack by creating really thin (5px height) transparent appbar, and then uses appbar's beforeShow and afterHide as the event I need. Do you think that's possible?

Comment: That might work, but I'm not sure if you can control the appbar height (I haven't tried styling one yet).  Also you'll want to manually hide the bar immediately after it shows so that is doesn't stay on screen and steal touch events from whatever it might be covering.

Comment: Thanks again @RichardBanks, I tried styling the height and it didn't work. Thanks for the suggestions. Specifically in my case, I am trying to postMessage to an iframe without displaying the native appbar. I just tried to adjust the appbar zindex to be less than my iframe zindex. It seems working just fine. I understand this is a temp hack and hope MSFT will introduce that event in the future. Thanks again.

Comment: Just another note for this post. I don't think you can set the height or the visibility of an app bar. At leaset it doesn't work for me.

Answer (score 1):

you can see the documentation for AppBar [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/br229670.aspx#events)

Appbar has four events: afterhide, aftershow, beforehide  and beforeshow.

Check the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/br229670.aspx) for more details

Comment: Thanks @TiagoAndradeSilva, but this is not what I meant. I mean the event that toggled AppBar, not the appbar events. I will edit the question to be more clear. Thanks