# Metro UI App Bar show on click button

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, window, microsoft-metro

I would like to show the bottom application bar based on a button. Is there any idea how to do so? I am working on Window 8 Consumer Preview Metro App.

Here is the Code for App Bar

```
<AppBar x:Name="GlobalAppBar" Padding="10,0,10,0">
            <Grid>
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="50*"/>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="50*"/>
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <StackPanel Margin="20,0,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Center">
                    <TextBlock x:Name="topBarText" Text="You can add stuff here as well .." FontSize="26" />
                </StackPanel>
            </Grid>
        </AppBar>
```

Normally the AppBar is shown based on right click of mouse while i wish to show it based on a button click event. Any idea? =D Please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can control how and when the app bar is shown and dismissed by setting the IsSticky and IsOpen properties. You can respond to the app bar being opened or dismissed by handling the Opened and Closed events.

taken from ["Quickstart: adding an app bar with commands" section Remarks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9040489/what-is-the-event-that-toggles-appbar-in-javascript-windows-8-metro-style-app)

Answer (score 1):

Can't imagine why you'd want to do it that way but you could try...

### Add a button to your page->

```
    <Button Content="App Bar open/close" Click="Button_Click_1" Margin="24,480,0,110" Grid.Row="1" />
```

### Then in the Click="Button_Click_1" event->

```
private void Button_Click_1(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (!this.BottomAppBar.IsOpen)
        {
            this.BottomAppBar.IsOpen = true;
        }
        else
        {
            this.BottomAppBar.IsOpen = false;
        }
    }
```

Just have fun trying...

Answer (score 0):

MyAppBar.IsOpen = true;

just try this in your event